# Problem with the connection Of Oracle Databse in SSRS

Tags: oracle, odbc

Not able to add New System DSN IN ODBC Data Source Administrator For Driver Microsoft ODBC For Oracle.
Trying to Configure Butsomehow The screen of ODBC Data Source Just Disappear.. Can anyone Please help me?

Comment: I'm sorry for downvoting your topic, I made this by mistake. :( About Microsoft ODBC driver for Oracle: as I remember MS does not support the driver anymore. I used Oracle ODBC drivers provided by Oracle and they worked well. So my suggestion is using ODBC driver produced by Oracle.